# HTML/JS dynamic loading from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, single-page-application

In my single-page `JS-app`, I've decided to dinamically load portions of `HTML/JS` in a `JIT` manner. I found 2 ways to do it, using `JQuery`:

**First:**

```
$("#target_div").load("html_and_js.html");    
// the HTML file contains both HTML` and the corresponding JS code
```

**Second:**

```
$("#target_div").load("thtml_only.html", function() {
    $.getScript('js/js_only.js');
}); // now the JS is kept separatelly from HTML
```

I would like to know your experiences and opinions regarding **pros/cons of both approaches**.

As I'm building an single-page `AJAX app`, I am particularly interested in the following aspects:

- Browswer performance if the large number of those dynamic loadings/removings are made - how much memory the modern browsers reserve for DOM?
- is the DOM structure kept safe and clean?
- when the corresponding DIV (`#target_div` in my example) is removed - is the JS also removed from the browser memory? Eventual memory leaks?

Every opinion is highely appreciated.

Comment: If you are really into single-page-approach then use Backbone.js. It'll allow you to organize all your code in a structured MVC manner.
[GotoBackboneHere](http://backbonejs.org/)

Comment: I decided to use only JQuery (and a JQuery based widgets library) for two reasons: 
1- to avoid risks of these frameworks becoming obsolete
2- to keep as much control as possible over the performance and design issues

Comment: Why don't look at using [requirejs][http://requirejs.org/] instead that way you'll have maintainable modules, also a good idea as single page apps tend to have a lot of JS floating around framework or not.

Answer (score 0):

From an architecture perspective you're separating out your presentation layer from business logic that may be held in the javascript - always good to do.

Separating your javascript into a separate file allows you to minify it easier, and re-use any of the functions that you develop into the javascript file.

Also, in the second option, the javascript will only get loaded once the html has completely loaded. Although as a rule of thumb I always recommend javascript goes as close to the end of the HTML document as possible, there are some (albeit rare) occasions where you need some portions of your javscript to run during the page load, not after it, and therefore the second approach (loading html first, then javascript on complete) wouldn't allow this javascript to run. Though... it could allow you to put the rare javscript that needs to be run into your HTML-only page (granted making it not-so-HTML-only), and keep the rest of the javascript separate for running at the end of the page.

Just my opinions, hope they help,

Kurt